# Google Maps Link in SSRS

Tags: google-maps, reporting-services, google-maps-markers, ssrs-2008-r2

I am currently trying to develop a report with a `google map` embedded on it. The `google map` will have a list of locations pointed on it. I was wondering If i could give links to those points which will take me to a sub report.

e.g. if I have 5 points on the google map representing 5 projects and If i click on the any one of the project pointer , it should take me the project details report.

Comment: What you have tried so far! post some code so that we can help...

Comment: I have a stored procedured which returns the URL of google map with markers of project location. Now I have the google map to be displayed as an image on my report